# convert scientific notation to decimal pandas python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Probably it is an old question, I found the similar questions below but I still can see the scientific notation in my output file.

[Suppressing scientific notation in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas)

[Pandas read scientific notation and change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013790/pandas-read-scientific-notation-and-change)

[Python Pandas Scientific Notation Iconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464334/python-pandas-scientific-notation-iconsistent)

I have tried to incorporate `set_option` and `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))` etc to my code below while do not work.

```
df = pd.read_csv(Input)  

dfNew = df[['co_A','co_B','co_C']]  
# I firstly select columns from df then would like to convert scientific notation to decimal type in my output file.

dfNew.to_csv(Output, index = False, sep = '\t')
```

Still I can see scientific notation in my output file. Anyone can help?

```
co_A  co_B  co_C
167 0.0 59.6
168 0.0 60.6
191 8e-09   72.6
197 -4.7718e-06 12.3
197 0.0 92.4
198 0.0 39.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `float_format` parameter when calling [.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function:

```
In [207]: df
Out[207]:
   co_A          co_B  co_C
0   167  0.000000e+00  59.6
1   168  0.000000e+00  60.6
2   191  8.000000e-09  72.6
3   197 -4.771800e-06  12.3
4   197  0.000000e+00  92.4
5   198  0.000000e+00  39.5

In [208]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\out.csv'

In [209]: df.to_csv(fn, index=False, sep='\t', float_format='%.6f')
```

out.csv:

```
co_A    co_B    co_C
167 0.000000    59.600000
168 0.000000    60.600000
191 0.000000    72.600000
197 -0.000005   12.300000
197 0.000000    92.400000
198 0.000000    39.500000
```