# Converting all rows in a pandas dataframe column from scientific notation to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert all rows in one column from a scientific notation to a float.  I am trying this solution below but getting a syntax error.  Does anyone have a better way of doing it?

```
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=15,freq='M')
forecast = model.predict(future)
forecast.tail(15)

forecast['yhat'] = df.apply({:.7f}.format(forecast['yhat']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: df['col1'].astype('float')?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert scientific notation to decimal pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810328/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimal-pandas-python)

Comment: It didnt work, I think the data in the column is being stored as a float which is correct but when I display it, it displays as scientific notation.  How can I force that its displays as a float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to force a display as decimal using [set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html?highlight=set_options)

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.7f}'.format)
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Value': np.random.rand(3)**22
})
df


    Name    Value
0   a   3.803715e-02
1   b   3.056442e-03
2   c   4.176117e-10

pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.7f}'.format)

    Name    Value
0   a   0.0380371
1   b   0.0030564
2   c   0.0000000


# reset the format option
pd.reset_option('display.float_format')
```